# Use suitable trigo angles to find the angles

Tags: trigonometry

> $\sec^{-1} (- \sqrt{2})  = \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Since $\sec x = \frac{1}{ \cos x } $

I am trying to prove that $\sec^{-1} (- \sqrt{2}) = \pi - \sec^{-1} ( \sqrt{2})$

Comment: I suggest to revise and edit your question indicating what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Or reformulate the main problem in a separate question.

Comment: You should also show your work.

Answer (score 1):

Who says you must remove the negative sign? It is certainly true that
$$\frac 1{\cos x} = -\sqrt2.$$

But the absolute value of the cosine function is never more than $1,$
so we can say for sure that

$$\frac 1{\cos x}  \neq \frac 1{\sqrt2} $$

and

$$\frac 1{\cos x}  \neq \frac 1{-\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2} =x$
Thus $$\sqrt{2} = \sec x$$
$$\Rightarrow -\sec \left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)=\sec x$$
$$\Rightarrow \sec \left(\pi \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}\right)=\sec x$$
Thus $x \text{ equals }\frac{7\pi}{4} \text{ or } \frac{\pi}{4}$
Thus $\pi - \sec^{-1} ( \sqrt{2})=\pi - \frac{7\pi}{4} \text{ or }\\\pi - \sec^{-1} ( \sqrt{2}) = \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}$
The given identity is satisfied in the 2nd case where $\sec^{-1}\sqrt{2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$